# How to check if a file is executable in go?

Tags: go, unix

How would I write a function to check whether a file is executable in Go? Given an `os.FileInfo`, I can get `os.FileInfo.Mode()`, but I stall out trying to parse the permission bits.

Test case:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function setup() {
  mkdir -p test/foo/bar
  touch test/foo/bar/{baz.txt,quux.sh}
  chmod +x test/foo/bar/quux.sh
}

function teardown() { rm -r ./test }

setup
```

```golang
import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "fmt"
)

func IsExectuable(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    // ???
}

func main() {
    filepath.Walk("test", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil || info.IsDir() {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v %v", path, IsExectuable(info.Mode().Perm()))
    }
}
// should print "test/foo/bar/baz.txt false"
//              "test/foo/bar/quux.txt true"
```

I only care about Unix files, but extra points if the solution works for Windows as well.

Comment: Executable by who? Owner? Group? Other?

Comment: I was wondering about whether a file was executable by the current user, but your more general answer is perfect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whether the file is executable is stored in the [Unix permission bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) (returned by [`FileMode.Perm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode.Perm) which are basically the lowest 9 bits (`0777` octal bitmask). Note that since we're using bitmasks in below solutions that mask out other bits anyway, calling `Perm()` is not necessary.

Their meaning is:

```
rwxrwxrwx
```

Where the first 3 bits are for the owner, the next 3 are for the group and the last 3 bits are for other.

To tell if the file is executable by its owner, use bitmask `0100`:

```
func IsExecOwner(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    return mode&0100 != 0
}
```

Similarly for telling if executable by the group, use bitmask `0010`:

```
func IsExecGroup(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    return mode&0010 != 0
}
```

And by others, use bitmask `0001`:

```
func IsExecOther(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    return mode&0001 != 0
}
```

To tell if the file is executable by any of the above, use bitmask `0111`:

```
func IsExecAny(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    return mode&0111 != 0
}
```

To tell if the file is executable by all of the above, again use bitmask `0111` but check if the result equals to `0111`:

```
func IsExecAll(mode os.FileMode) bool {
    return mode&0111 == 0111
}
```

Comment: The POSIX system call to check whether the current user (based on the real UID and GID) can execute a file is [`access`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html) with `X_OK`. This should also take the file's ACL into account on platforms that support ACLs, such as Linux.

Comment: whats the answer for "executable for the current user"? This is not the same as IsExecOwner I think??

Comment: @Gabriel If the file owner is the current user, then `IsExecOwner()`. Else if current user is in the group of the file, then `IsExecGroup()`, else `IsExecOther()`.

Comment: Ok, so I need https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix to do that . Thx

Comment: But how to test this? If the user is in the group?

Comment: is it just: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Access wiht `mode := X_OK` ?

Comment: How to do that on windows with go?

Answer (score 1):

The other comments are correct, in that the permission bits on the file are not sufficient to tell conclusively if the file is executable by the current user, certainly without the file's ownership. In fact, executable by the current user is in a sense meaningless, as what counts to the system is if the current *process* can execute a file, whether or not the current user typically can (e.g. a setuid/setgid situation) from say their shell prompt.

I'm not a go programmer, but I have added a function [here](https://gitlab.com/stellarpower-grouped-projects/tidbits/go/-/blob/main/CheckFileExecutable.go#L10) that I believe performs the trick and uses what has been already mentioned.