# How to check if a file is executable on Windows with golang?

Tags: windows, go

From the question below, I was able to figure out how to check if it can be run on a posix compatible file system.

[How to check if a file is executable in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128401/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-executable-in-go)

However, I don't think this works for Windows. Is there a good way?

Comment: Checking its extension of the file may help?

Comment: What's your practical use case? Typically one would just try to run the file via `CreateProcessW` -- or however the language wraps the Windows API -- and deal with an access-denied error by searching for a different file to run, logging, or prompting the user.

Comment: My use case is to use kustomize's exec plugins on windows too. kustomize uses `os.Stat` to check if the plugin is executable, but this doesn't work on Windows. (see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2924)

Comment: Checking access is discouraged since it's race-prone, but if you have to do it in POSIX, you should use `faccessat` with `X_OK` and `AT_EACCESS` in order to evaluate the file's mode and ACL permissions against the effective user and group IDs and supplementary groups of the process. Windows has `AccessCheck` with which you can check for `FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE` access. First you have to call `OpenThreadToken` (or, if that fails, `OpenProcessToken` and `DuplicateToken`) to get an impersonation token and `GetNamedSecurityInfoW` to get the file security (owner, label, attribute, and DACL).

Comment: Also note that Windows thinks of files very differently than Linux; typically in Linux, only a file that *can* be executed has execute permissions, whereas on Windows, practically every file has execute permissions, whether or not it's actually an executable file. So checking file perms for execute may not actually tell you what you're trying to find out.

Comment: @Adrian, read and execute access are usually assigned together in Windows, but they're separate rights. `CreateProcessW` and `LoadLibraryExW` require execute access. OTOH, `ShellExecuteExW` only requires read access to execute (open) data files, including scripts. CMD ensures execute access is granted by always trying `CreateProcessW` first. It won't try `ShellExecuteExW` if `CreateProcessW` fails with access denied. PowerShell, OTOH, doesn't care about the latter. It's more lenient (less secure).

Comment: The discretionary and mandatory security inherited from the parent directory usually grants standard users both read and execute access. Except a user profile directory only grants access to the owning user, administrators, and system. Other users have no access. Another set of exceptions to the norm are app directories in "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps". These directories have an inheritable conditional ACE that only grants execute access to a standard user if the access token contains the particular app's "WIN://SYSAPPID" in a security attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen four ways of doing this:

### [AccessCheck](//learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheck)

Based on this comment:

> Windows has `AccessCheck` with which you can check for `FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE`
> access. First you have to call `OpenThreadToken` (or, if that fails,
> `OpenProcessToken` and `DuplicateToken`) to get an impersonation token and
> `GetNamedSecurityInfoW` to get the file security (owner, label, attribute, and
> DACL).

I found a Go package with the function [UserHasPermission](//pkg.go.dev/github.com/itchio/ox/winox#UserHasPermission). I think this is the correct method to do this.

### [GetBinaryTypeW](//learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getbinarytypew)

Used by [PHP](//github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.2/win32/ioutil.c#L673) and [Rust](//github.com/fitzgen/is_executable/blob/v1.0.1/src/lib.rs#L146). This checks if a file if of executable **type**, but
does check executable **permission**.

### [GetFileAttributesW](//learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw)

Used by [Go](//github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.15.8/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L624) and [Python](//github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Modules/posixmodule.c#L2904) and [Nim](//github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-4/lib/pure/os.nim#L1632). The logic here is all files are readable and
executable, and only differentiates on if a file is writable.

### [GetFileInformationByHandle](//learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle)

Used by [Ruby](//github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_0_0/win32/win32.c#L5492). The logic here is all files are readable and executable, and only
differentiates on if a file is writable.