# Whats the golang equivalent of test -x in shell?

Tags: go

The answer `IsExecOwner(file string)` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60128480/293195 addresses the topic but  I am not sure if that is the equivalent to `test -x` in POSIX Shell? If the user is in the group of that file and the group has the executable bit set, this solution is probably not correct.

Do I need to consult https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix

Answer (score 0):

It's

```golang
func Access(path string, mode uint32) (err error)
```

in https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Access
with `mode := X_OK` Referenz: https://linux.die.net/man/2/access